# Clarification on the notation $L^\infty(w(y) dy)$

Tags: real-analysis, notation, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to understand Besov spaces at the moment and in one characterisation, the space $L^r(dy/|y|^\alpha)$ is used. The $y$ denotes an element of $\mathbb R^n$. I know what this is for $r<\infty$, but for $r=\infty$, is it: $f\in L^\infty(dy/|y|^\alpha)$ iff

1. $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ (i.e. with standard Lebesgue measure) ? or
2. $|y|^{-\alpha}f\in  L^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$?

(For $p<\infty$, people write $f\in L^p(d\mu)$ iff $\int |f|^p d\mu < \infty$.)

Does this hold more generally for other weights $w(y)dy$; and in general for arbitrary measures $\mu,\nu$, is $L^\infty(\mu)= L^\infty(\nu)$ if their nullsets are the same? Or is it defined to be something else?

Comment: I added the tag Harmonic analysis and Fourier Analysis,since i believe that Besov spaces and weighted inequalities in general  belong to this field.

Comment: @MariosGretsas reasonable. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is right, not 2). Yes, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ have the same null sets then $L^{\infty} (\mu) $ is same as $L^{\infty} (\nu) $.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot Kabo :) [will accept answer later since I can't right now]